# Не могу подключиться к бд из виртуальной машины

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, postgresql, macos, mac

Используя postgress app для mac создал бд.

Из мака проблем с подключением нет, а при подключении из вм(parallels)
падает ошибка. Открыл порты и на маке и на винде и все равно ошибка не уходит, что делать не знаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выполнить аналогичный запрос на маке, все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас разрешено подключение только с localhost.

Вам необходимо выполнить два действия:

1) Указать IP-адрес интерфейса через который подключается виртуальная машина. Сделать это нужно в файле конфигурации Postgresql сервера (postgresql.conf), добавив строку:

```
listen_addresses = '<IP шлюза>'
```

Или для всех интерфейсов:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

2) Отредактировать файл pg_hba.conf (его расположение можно узнать, выполнив SQL-запрос 'show hba_file;') добавив в него IP-адреса скоторых разрешена авторизация по паролю:

```
host all all <IP виртуальной машины> md5
```

После этих действий необходимо перезапустить сервер.

Предполагаю, что в вашем случае это должно выглядеть так:

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = 192.168.0.101
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5
```

Comment: И если надо добавить вход без ssl
hostnossl all  all  0.0.0.0/0 md5